# How to solve the aws appsync mutation timeout issue?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have a lambda that performs mutations to delete a bunch of items, but the timeout issue always occurs.

This is the function I use to delete items from the dynamoDB. I pass a list of objects to be removed into the deleteExpiredFcm function. From the log message, I know the mutation is having some kind of conflict that causes the timeout issue. Also, I implemented pagination to avoid the timeout issue, as the object list may consist of hundreds or even thousands of items. What am I missing?

```
async function deleteExpiredFcm(expiredFcm) {
  console.log("Deleting expired FCM...");
  const batchSize = 10; // Adjust the batch size as needed
  const totalBatches = Math.ceil(expiredFcm.length / batchSize);

  for (let i = 0; i < totalBatches; i++) {
    const batch = expiredFcm.slice(i * batchSize, (i + 1) * batchSize);

    const mutationPromises = batch.map(async (element) => {
      const mutationObj = deleteExpiredFcmObj;
      const variables = {
        input: {
          id: element.id,
        },
      };

      let retries = 3; // Number of retries
      let success = false;

      while (retries > 0 && !success) {
        try {
          const { data } = await client.mutate({
            mutation: mutationObj,
            variables: variables,
          });
          console.log(
            "(Mutation): Deleting Data ----------->",
            data.deleteFcmNotification
          );
          success = true;
        } catch (error) {
          if (
            error.graphQLErrors.some(
              (err) => err.errorType === "ConflictUnhandled"
            )
          ) {
            console.log("Conflict occurred, retrying...");
            retries--;
          } else {
            console.error("Error deleting FCM:", error);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    });

    await Promise.all(mutationPromises); // Await the completion of each batch
  }
}
```

Edit:
I added _version to the mutation input, so it deletes items now. However I'm still getting the timeout issue,
{
"errorMessage": "2023-06-13T12:56:25.895Z 7c81deb4-ccea-4cf0-ac59-f72c5e1becf9 Task timed out after 3.05 seconds"
}

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the GraphQL error, I added _version to the mutation input.

```
const variables = {
    input: {
      id: element.id,
      _version: element._version,
    },
};
```

To solve the timeout issue, I simply increased the timeout limit in the lambda general configuration. This solves the issue for now. Please let me know if there is a more proper way to solve the timeout issue.